# Why mathematica can't evaluate this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why mathematica can't evaluate this integral? It just gives me symbolic form. I can work it out by hand.

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[2*Pi*\[Tau]^2]^n Exp[-1/(2*\[Tau]^2) * \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\(\((
\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(\(i\)\(\ \)\)] - \ \[Alpha]\  - \ \[Beta]*
\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(i - 1\)])\)^2\)\)] 1/
   Sqrt[2 Pi Subscript[\[Sigma], 
      1]^2] Exp[-1/(2*Subscript[\[Sigma], 1]^2) * (\[Alpha] - 
       Subscript[\[Mu], 1])^2 ] 1/
   Sqrt[2 Pi Subscript[\[Sigma], 
      2]^2] Exp[-1/(2*Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]^2) * (\[Beta] - 
       Subscript[\[Mu], 2])^2] , 
 {\[Alpha], -Infinity, Infinity}, {\[Beta], -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Comment: Works fine if you fix the value of $n$ instead of leaving it unspecified, and add the option `GenerateConditions -> False` to the `Integrate` command.

Comment: @Roman: Your suggestion does not work for `n=13` (The command is spinning forever.).

Comment: @user64494 my point is that Mathematica has trouble operating on symbolic sums. Naturally, when we specify $n$ too large it runs into expression complexity problems, which are due to insufficient calculation resources (time, memory) and not due to algorithmic deficiencies.

Comment: Are4 all the constants real?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes.

Answer (score 1):

The form of the integrand is quite simple, but the indeterminate `Sum` is beyond Mathematica's current analytical abilities. Simplify the integrand to a Gaussian and then solve for the coefficients of the Gaussian:

```
integrand = 1/Sqrt[2*Pi*\[Tau]^2]^n Exp[-1/(2*\[Tau]^2) * \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\(\((
\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(\(i\)\(\ \)\)] - \ \[Alpha]\  - \ \[Beta]*
\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(i - 1\)])\)^2\)\)] 1/
       Sqrt[2 Pi Subscript[\[Sigma], 
              1]^2] Exp[-1/(2*Subscript[\[Sigma], 1]^2) * (\[Alpha] - 
               Subscript[\[Mu], 1])^2 ] 1/
       Sqrt[2 Pi Subscript[\[Sigma], 
              2]^2] Exp[-1/(2*Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]^2) * (\[Beta] - 
               Subscript[\[Mu], 2])^2];
newintegrand = integrand /. 
   Power[E, _] :> 
    Exp[-(c + a \[Alpha] + b \[Beta] + aa \[Alpha]^2 + ab \[Alpha]*\[Beta] + 
        bb \[Beta]^2)];

ClearAll[myCoefficient];
myCoefficient[HoldPattern[c_.*Sum[arg_, iter__]]] := 
  Function[x, c*Sum[x, iter], Listable][
   CoefficientList[arg, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}, {3, 3}]];
myCoefficient[e_Plus] := myCoefficient[#] & /@ e;
myCoefficient[e_] := CoefficientList[e, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}, {3, 3}];

Cases[integrand, p : Power[E, x_] :> 
   myCoefficient[x] == 
    myCoefficient[-(c + a \[Alpha] + b \[Beta] + aa \[Alpha]^2 + 
        ab \[Alpha]*\[Beta] + bb \[Beta]^2)], Infinity];
params = First@Solve[%, {a, b, c, aa, ab, bb}];

res = Integrate[newintegrand, 
      {\[Alpha], -Infinity, Infinity}, {\[Beta], -Infinity, Infinity}, 
     Assumptions -> aa > 0 && bb > 0 && ab^2 - 4 aa*bb < 0] /. params;
res // TeXForm
```

$$\frac{(2 \pi )^{-n/2} \left(\tau
   ^2\right)^{-n/2} \exp
   \left(\frac{-\frac{\left(\sigma _2^2 \sum
   _{i=1}^n y_{i-1}^2+\tau ^2\right)
   \left(\sigma _1^2 \sum _{i=1}^n -2 y_i-2 \mu
   _1 \tau ^2\right){}^2}{8 \sigma _1^4 \sigma
   _2^2 \tau ^6}+\frac{\left(\sum _{i=1}^n 2
   y_{i-1}\right) \left(\sigma _2^2 \sum
   _{i=1}^n -2 y_{i-1} y_i-2 \mu _2 \tau
   ^2\right) \left(\sigma _1^2 \sum _{i=1}^n -2
   y_i-2 \mu _1 \tau ^2\right)}{8 \sigma _1^2
   \sigma _2^2 \tau ^6}-\frac{\left(n \sigma
   _1^2+\tau ^2\right) \left(\sigma _2^2 \sum
   _{i=1}^n -2 y_{i-1} y_i-2 \mu _2 \tau
   ^2\right){}^2}{8 \sigma _1^2 \sigma _2^4
   \tau ^6}}{\frac{\left(\sum _{i=1}^n 2
   y_{i-1}\right){}^2}{4 \tau ^4}-\frac{\left(n
   \sigma _1^2+\tau ^2\right) \left(\sigma _2^2
   \sum _{i=1}^n y_{i-1}^2+\tau
   ^2\right)}{\sigma _1^2 \sigma _2^2 \tau
   ^4}}-\frac{\sigma _2^2 \sigma _1^2
   \left(\sum _{i=1}^n y_i^2\right)+\mu _2^2
   \sigma _1^2 \tau ^2+\mu _1^2 \sigma _2^2
   \tau ^2}{2 \sigma _1^2 \sigma _2^2 \tau
   ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\sigma _2^2} \sqrt{-\sigma
   _1^2 \left(\frac{\left(\sum _{i=1}^n 2
   y_{i-1}\right){}^2}{4 \tau ^4}-\frac{\left(n
   \sigma _1^2+\tau ^2\right) \left(\sigma _2^2
   \sum _{i=1}^n y_{i-1}^2+\tau
   ^2\right)}{\sigma _1^2 \sigma _2^2 \tau
   ^4}\right)}}$$

The sums probably can be simplified, but Mathematica does not combine them.